# How do you append a new list to a an existing dictionary in JSON file

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to make a list of classrooms with the students in them. But I'm trying to append it using variables, to a dictionary in a JSON file. My current JSON file looks like this:

```
[{"History": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"]}]
```

But I want to add a new list so it can look like this:

```
[{"Hisotry": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"], "Calculus": ["billy", "sammy"]}]
```

I have this code where I would have the variable `classRoom` be the class and `studentName` be the student. I tried appending the new list to the entire file by changing the data type of dict but I keep getting an error saying "Key word can't be an expression." when I try to run it.

```
with open('students.json') as p:
      data = json.load(p)
if type (data) is dict:
      data = [data]
#classRoom = [studentName]
data.append([str(classRoom)] = [str(studentName)])
with open ('students.json', 'w') as outfile:
          json.dump(data,outfile)
 print "Success added new student to classroom"
```

I also tried to create a list before I add it to the dictionary, doing  `classRoom = [studentName]` and then appending it doing `data.append(classRoom)` but only the list gets appended and not the classRoom name. So the JSON file ends up looking like this.

```
[{"History": ["sally", "billy", "tommy"], ["sally"]}]
```

I'm trying have both the classroom name and the students in the file but I am not sure what I am doing wrong to try to add the new list to the file. Any help on how I can do this or what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
data.append([str(classRoom)] = [str(studentName)])
```

This is wrong, you can not assign to a function call. I'm also not sure about all the conversions to `str`.

Simply assigne as a new key in the first dict in the list (assuming `classRoom` is  the string `"Calculus"` and `studentName` is the list `["billy", "sammy"]`):

```
data[0][classRoom] = studentName
```

Answer (score 0):

You Data structure is list of dictionary. And you want to add to your dictionary not to your list.

In python `list` accept the method `append`. If you append anything to the list, it stays in the list.

The key, value you want add is to your dictionary i.e., an element of the list so, if you want to update your dictionary then you need to access the dictionary first then add new key, value to the dictionary.

Adding a new element to dictionary is like below

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d["item1"] = "value1"
>>> print(d)
{"item1":"value1"}
```

Your code can be like below

```
data[0][classRoom] = [list of students]
```